# Injecting "module" into AMD require callback

Tags: requirejs, amd

So say I have this:

```
 require(['suman', 'module'], function (suman, module) {

    console.log('module:', module);  // ? what is module supposed to represent here?

    const Test = suman.init();
    Test.create((describe, it) => {

      it('too much', t => {

      });

    });

  });
```

I am confused - what does `module` actually mean in this context?

I understand what `module` would be for in this context:

```
define('foo', ['module'], function(module){

   // module is used to create exports, of course!
   module.exports.bar = 'bar'; 

});
```

does anyone know what module might represent in the context of an AMD `require()` callback?

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to retrieve various metadata about the module, including configuration.

[Here is the documentation.](https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/wiki/Differences-between-the-simplified-CommonJS-wrapper-and-standard-AMD-define#module)

Comment: `module` makes sense in the context of a `define` callback, but not the in the context of a `require` callback, right? I don't know what `module` means in a `require` callback. see my response to jburke: https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/1709

Comment: oh i get it. why are you asking here @AlexanderMills. you went to the right place first.

Comment: ok glad you get it now, thanks - but yeah I try to avoid asking "support" related questions in Github, but this is one of those in-between questions. Have I piqued your curiosity on what `module` might mean in the context of a require() callback? I am hoping my question does not get downvoted

Comment: @AlexanderMills maybe global config

Comment: what do you mean by global config?